# Parameter value on callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

So, I wanna know why this code actually display "Done!" on execution, I'm studying callbacks right now and I cannot grasp the value of the parameter "text" when this code is executed. I'm deeply sorry if my question seems vague or incomplete, I've tried to research as much as I could but this is indeed my first time asking something on StackOverflow. Thanks for reading.

```
const fetchData = (callback) => {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        callback('Done!');
    },1500);
};

setTimeout(()=>{
    fetchData( (text) => {
        console.log(text);
    });
},2000);
```

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have firstly defined `fetchData` function, which calls it's argument (which is a function) with `Done!` argument after 1.5 seconds. So you have prepared a function, but you didn't execute it yet. That `setTimeout` below will executes `fetchData` after 2 seconds and as argument will be function, in this case `fat arrow` (or simply `arrow function`) which is basically that `callback` in `fetchData` and as this `callback` needs some argument to show (variable `text`) and we pass to it that argument `Done!` (`(text) => { console.log(text); }` is `callback` in `fetchData`)

Answer (score 1):

Text is the parameter of the callback function. In this example it is the text: Done!

The entire function is getting passed into fetchData, then fetchData calls the callback and passes in Done!

```
//This is what is happening....

callback = (text) => {
    console.log(text)
}

callback('Done!')
```